# Unit testing for compiler errors

Tags: c++, unit-testing, error-handling

How do you test for wanted raised compiler errors in unit testing?

Consider the code:

```
class ErrorTest
{
    OtherClass& read_write() {
        return other;
    }

    const OtherClass& read_only() const {
        return other;
    }

    private:
        OtherClass other;
};
```

How can I test for read_only() assignment? It's really important and should be firmly checked to properly generate compiler errors:

```
ErrorTest test;
OtherClass other = test.read_only();
test.read_write() = other.modify();
test.read_only() = other.modify(); /* This should error */
```

Comment: Good question. I've wondered the same before. Never really found a good answers though. Of course you could write a script that attempts to compile the file, and verifies the error code or something, but it's hardly an elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

I guess the main question now is, are you testing that your code or the compiler at this point?

Testing the compiler isn't necessarily a bad thing... I've had compiler upgrades mask errors in the past, so it would be nice to ensure that you are getting the same set of safety checks that you expect.

However, you'll have to do a lot of legwork. Your unit test will have to spawn the compiler, capture it's output, and parse it for the correct error statement on the correct line. It's not trivial, and arguably not worth it.

A slightly easier approach might be to keep a directory of bad code, and have a script compile each file one at a time. Have an '#ifdef MAKEFAIL' flag in there that turns on the exact condition that should fail. Ensure the compiler returns 0 when you don't set that flag, and non-zero when you do. That assumes that the compiler returns non-zero on failure... I don't know if MSVC follows that rule.

A third option I'll throw out there, to address portability, is autoconf. It can be a pain to set up, but part of its purpose was to ensure that you have a sane development environment before compiling. You could add a test like this in it, and it let handle finding the compiler and trying it.

Comment: He is testing that his code is const-correct. So I think he is still testing his code, it's just that he's testing properties of it which are only evident at compile time.

Comment: I read that as he is trying to ensure that the compiler is generating the warnings, not that there are no warnings. It seems a little redundant to have a unit test tell you that your compilation complained, but perhaps if you have a nice unit-test-output-parser it makes sense.

Comment: He's trying to ensure that the compiler produces an error, not a warning. There are plenty of cases in C++ where this makes sense. Const correctness is one example, but if you're playing with templates, it also occurs often.

Comment: Probably can simplify it by just checking return code on compiler, without parsing output. But must have a corresponding control files for each test, that would actually compile (everything the same, but offending line called properly or commented out). So test passes when one file compiles and one fails for each case.

Comment: (Or same use one file per test but #ifdef offending code for second compilation)

Comment: @Chris: he's trying to catch the programmer error of forgetting to mark the return value from read_only as const. So if the code read "OtherClass &read_only()" instead of "const OtherClass &read_only() const", then the test code would compile instead of giving an error, and he wants that to be a test fail. I think.

Comment: I really like the second approach but I question it's portability, especially when working using several compilers (GCC, ICC and MSVC) across operating systems. Will a bash script do?

Answer (score 1):

This seems a little like the automatic detection that happens when you "./configure" for a build from source on a *nix machine.  The autoconf scripts build little programs and attempt to compile them to determine what's available and supported by your compiler.

It probably isn't practical to reuse any of that, but you might want the same model.  Each test would have its own file or set of files, and a separate project file/make target/etc..  Then your test script would attempt to make each test case and check that the expected error occurred, either via grep or by comparing the output to a baseline output stored with the test cases.

Answer (score 0):

A valid test of the compiler and platform would be for runtime variations in behavior. I often do this, reproducing small bits of behaviors that exist within my production code, and checking that the behavior is as expected.

But for this case what you really want is a static analysis tool, that checks to make sure the code that your developers write follows conventions such as this one. That is certainly a valid build tool. However, searching for a static analysis tool to find what you're specifying here might be difficult. I'd start with the Wikipedia article [List of tools for static code analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis), in the [C/C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#C.2FC.2B.2B) section.

Note that the code you've written isn't an "error", it's merely your convention. It's a very good convention, but the compiler does not and should not constrain you to that convention. And neither should a static analysis tool. Therefore you'll need to find one that allows you to configure what is allowable and what is not.

Comment: Sadly, cppcheck doesn't work for this type of error: "$ cppcheck main.cpp Checking main.cpp: ... No errors found"

Comment: Is there a way to configure cppcheck? It doesn't look like it. That's what you'll need to do to enforce your convention.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, you can use

`std::is_const< decltype( std::declval<ErrorTest>().read_only() ) >::value`

to know on compile-time (or runtime as you want) if this return type is const.